# What are the arguments for QgsDistanceArea().setSourceCrs()

Tags: qgis, python

I am really struggling with migrating a custom plugin from QGIS 2.x to 3.x. Below is a code snippet that seems very straightforward, but I can't find documentation that I understand for setSourceCrs().

```
  # First, make sure the point is not within a half meter of the start
  # or end points.
  da = QgsDistanceArea()

  # Function call in API 2.x
  # da.setSourceCrs(lyrDb.lyr.crs().srsid())

  # My attempt is missing the second argument
  da.setSourceCrs(lyrDb.lyr.sourceCrs())

  line = parent.geometry().asPolyline()
  n = len(line)
  d = da.measureLine(line[0], p1)
  if d < 0.5:
    return 0
  d = da.measureLine(line[n - 1], p1)
  if d < 0.5:
    return 0
```

As you can see, previously the only argument required for the function was an integer for SRID. The new API wants two arguments as shown below, but very little explanation. Taken from https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/index.html

```
void QgsDistanceArea::setSourceCrs (const QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem & crs, const QgsCoordinateTransformContext & context)
```

I think I have the first argument correct, but I have no idea about the second. What do I need to send for the context argument?

Are there any other sources for documentation for the API?

This solution worked for me. It essentially passes an empty parameter into context, but that's okay because I'm not doing a transformation. I tested and it works as expected.

```
  # First, make sure the point is not within a half meter of the start
  # or end points.
  da = QgsDistanceArea()
  context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
  da.setSourceCrs(lyrDb.lyr.crs(), context)
  line = parent.geometry().asPolyline()
  n = len(line)
  d = da.measureLine(line[0], p1)
  if d < 0.5:
    return -1
  d = da.measureLine(line[n - 1], p1)
  if d < 0.5:
    return -1
```

For the record, though it helped, my question was not solved by [Calculate ellipsoidal area for a projected layer in PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285571/calculate-ellipsoidal-area-for-a-projected-layer-in-pyqgis-3), nor is it a duplicate IMO.

That question was specifically concerned with calculating an ellipsoidal area which requires a transformation. The code that I am migrating concerns only a projected layer, which does not involve a transformation.

I came here after spending hours searching for an answer, and in my opinion it is because the documentation for pyQGIS API is sparse at best. However, I fully admit that the post above helped me figure out my solution, assuming it is a solution. It appears to work, and that is all I can say. Surely, there must be a proper way to call setSourceCrs when no transformation is required.

That said, I am happy so feel free to do whatever is appropriate with this question. This is my first foray into StackExchange, and I'm not familiar with protocol.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, that helped.

Comment: This question can probably be closed, but I would really like to know the correct answer if anyone knows what it is.

Comment: Actually it's not correct - you should get the transform context from the user's current project via QgsProject.instance().transformContext()

Comment: @ndawson Thank you! Please turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it.