# Calculating elipsoidal length of line in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, line, length, ellipsoid

I am using PyQGIS with QGIS 3.

This code below is what I developed already, what I am doing wrong?

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
feature = layer.getFeatures()

for feat in feature:
    feature.setSourceCrs(##What goes here?)
    print (QgsDistanceArea.measureLength(feat))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use just `QgsDistanceArea.measureLength(feat)`, you get an error: `first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsDistanceArea'`. That means you need to create an object of `QgsDistanceArea`

```py
d = QgsDistanceArea()
```

Then you need to set ellipsoid. Use `QgsEllipsoidUtils::acronyms()` to get a list of all known ellipsoid acronyms. If you don't set ellipsoid, calculations will be performed in plane geometry.

```py
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
```

Then you can use `measureLength` to get the length of the line on ellipsoid. Normally the measurement is in meters.

```py
measure = d.measureLength(feat.geometry())
```

Or you can use `measureLine` method instead of `measureLength`.

```py
measure = d.measureLine(feat.geometry().asPolyline())

# If geometry type is multipolyline
measure = d.measureLine(feat.geometry().asMultiPolyline()[0])
```

For more information, please review [QgsDistanceArea](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/other/QgsDistanceArea.html) documentation.

Answer (score 8):

This is my answer:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
features = layer.getFeatures()

d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setSourceCrs(layer.crs(), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
d.setEllipsoid(QgsProject.instance().ellipsoid())

for feat in features:
    print((d.convertLengthMeasurement(d.measureLength(feat.geometry()), 1))*1000)
```

Answer (score 6):

One way could be:

```py
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
features = layer.getFeatures()

for feat in features:
    print(
        d.convertAreaMeasurement(
            d.measureLength(feat.geometry()),
            1
        )
    )
```

Comment: It worked, but in the case i want use the projected coordinate system, what should I do?

`````layer = iface.activeLayer() 

feature = layer.getFeatures()

lyr_crs = layer.crs()

trans_context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()

trans_context.calculateDatumTransforms(lyr_crs, elps_crs)

d = QgsDistanceArea()

d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

d.setSourceCrs(lyr_crs, trans_context)

for feat in feature:

    print(d.convertAreaMeasurement(d.measureLength(feat.geometry()),1))`````

Comment: You are correct, you have to use a transformation context, check this post it will help you [Calculate ellipsoidal area for a projected layer in PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285571/calculate-ellipsoidal-area-for-a-projected-layer-in-pyqgis-3)

Comment: ``
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
feature = layer.getFeatures()

d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setSourceCrs(layer.crs(), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
d.setEllipsoid(QgsProject.instance().ellipsoid())
for feat in feature:
    print(d.convertLengthMeasurement(d.measureLength(feat.geometry()),1))``

Comment: Thanks, the answer is below:

```layer = iface.activeLayer() 
feature = layer.getFeatures()

d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setSourceCrs(layer.crs(), QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
d.setEllipsoid(QgsProject.instance().ellipsoid())
for feat in feature:
    print(d.convertLengthMeasurement(d.measureLength(feat.geometry()),1))```

Comment: @vitorcsm Please feel free to add your comment as the answer of your question.