# How to batch calculate vector layer road lengths in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, batch, road

I'm trying to calculate the road length for hundreds of layers, each one being a small road vector layer. I usually follow the process at

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html

which is basically creating a new field in the Field Calculator, entering `$length`, and looking at the sum in Summary Statistics. Is there a way to rapidly do this for all layers so I get a list of layers and the length of each?

Comment: i'm sure the solution exists on this site already! You could generate a small python script to do this or use a model in QGIS to do in batch.

For the python solution - it would involve a script that does the following:
1.) iterate over list of layers (or files in a directory!)
2.) add column/field
3.) populate the new column with $length

Comment: You might merge your layers, add the length field and calculate it.  To get the total for each layer run a dissolve and recalculate the lengths.   You can use the split vector tool on either to get individual layers back with the new information in each.

Answer (score 1):

One solution amongst multiple possibilities. You need to select your layers and they need to be lines.

```py
selected_layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

for layer in selected_layers:
    print(f"{layer.name()} : {sum([f.geometry().length() for f in layer.getFeatures()])}")
```

or to always get meters units by using ellipsoidal length (borrowed from [Calculating elipsoidal length of line in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347802/calculating-elipsoidal-length-of-line-in-pyqgis/347825))

```
import pandas as pd

selected_layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

result = []
for layer in selected_layers:
    tot = 0
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        m = d.measureLength(f.geometry())
        if m > 0:
            tot += m
    print(f"{layer.name()} : {tot}")
    result.append([{layer.name()}, f"{tot}"])

# To get a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['layer_name', 'tot'])
df.to_csv("your_layers_count.csv", index=False)

# For export to CSV without pandas deps, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037540/writing-a-python-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file
```

Comment: How do I get this output? i.e. save as csv? I stored these values in a pandas dataframe

Comment: Edited my 2nd answer