# Calculating line lengths of road network in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, line, geometry, length

I have a road network `'TR_ROAD'` with EPSG:4283 crs and 1200 features. I am trying to calculate length of each line segment in road by using `"length"` geometry in PyQGIS.

When I tried below code, the PyQGIS editor got hanged for long time and program terminates.

I followed the existing answers to [Calculating line lengths using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168871/calculating-line-lengths-using-pyqgis) and [Calculating elipsoidal length of line in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347802/calculating-elipsoidal-length-of-line-in-pyqgis/347825), but they didn't work for me.

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('TR_ROAD')[0]
features = layer.getFeatures()

for f in features:
    geom = f.geometry()
    leng = geom.length()
    res = layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Length", QVariant.Int)])
    layer.updateFields()


with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures(): #For each feature/line in the layer calculate length
        f['Length'] = f.geometry().length()/1000
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are adding the field once for each feature, you only need to add the field once for the table.

When updating features like this:

```
with edit(layer):
    ....
```

I have found it often hangs with many features (thousands).

Try storing the new data in a dictionary, and update with `changeAttributeValues`.

Like this:

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('jl_riks_wgs84')[0]
p = lyr.dataProvider()
p.addAttributes([QgsField('Length', QVariant.Double)])
lyr.updateFields()

distance = QgsDistanceArea()
distance.setEllipsoid(lyr.crs().ellipsoidAcronym())

fieldindex = lyr.fields().indexFromName('Length')
attrmap = {} #Dictionary of {feature id: {field index: field value}}

for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    leng = distance.measureLength(f.geometry())
    attrmap[f.id()] = {fieldindex:leng}
p.changeAttributeValues(attrmap)
```

[image]